# Have Windows Authentication use default login page instead of popup dialog in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, authentication, windows-authentication

Is there a way to have simple windows authentication for a public facing site (anonymous viewing is enabled so as to view the login page) but insatead of it popping up the windows auth dialog, to use a login page (aspx). I saw something similar when i switched to mixed mode authentication. SharePoint has a dropdown with "windows authentication" or "forms authentication". What i need is something similar, but just the "windows authentication" option.

I've seen similar questions on SO, but they all involve creating a custom login page. The ideal solution would involve no new pages and no coding.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done by launching the sharepoint page's address in internet explorer, and using some pinvoke api to send keys or settext to the login box.

I fanagled this setup for a vb.net forms application.  It works on my XP.  I haven't tried it in Windows 7 yet, but I'm sure it needs some adjustment for it to work there.

This uses a library called WindowScraper, from here: http://www.programmersheaven.com/download/56171/download.aspx

This library has a bunch of winapi and pinvoke built in.  If your assembly won't allow it (because you are using VS 2010, perhaps), saying it doesn't have a strong name, then use SharpDevelop and rebuild the solution after adding your own certificate.

Then put the dll in your application directory and add a reference.

Then add the imports:

```
Imports WindowScrape
Imports WindowScrape.Constants
Imports WindowScrape.Types
```

Finally, the code (put all this in a module or class):

Private Property PortalAddress As String = "http://myportal@somewhere.com"
Private Property logintitle As String = "Connect to myportal@somewhere.com"

Public Sub openPortal()

```
If My.Computer.Info.OSFullName = "Microsoft Windows XP Professional" then 
    LoginToPortalXP()
Else
    msgbox("Someday, we will be able to log you in automatically" & vbCr & "But it isn't ready yet.")
End If
End Sub

Private Function IsWindowReady(Optional ByVal timeout As integer = 10000)
    Dim isready As Boolean = false
    Dim timer As Integer = 1000
    Do Until Not loginBox is nothing or timer = timeout
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
        loginbox = HwndObject.GetWindowByTitle(logintitle)
        timer = timer + 1000
    loop
    If Not loginbox is nothing then isready = true
    Return isready
End Function

Sub LoginToPortalXP()
    Try
        Dim TheBrowser As Object = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        TheBrowser.Visible = True
        TheBrowser.Navigate(PortalAddress)
        If Not IsWindowReady then debug.print("failed") : Exit sub

        Dim sys As HwndObject = loginbox.GetChildren(1)   'SysCredential
        sys.GetChildren(1).Text = "myUserName"  'username box
        Thread.Sleep(500)
        sys.GetChildren(4).Text = "myPassword"   'password box
        Thread.Sleep(500)
        loginbox.GetChildren(2).Click()     'push the okay button
    Catch ex As Exception
        msgbox("ERROR AutoLogging into Portal: " & vbcr & & ex.Message)
    Finally        
    End Try
End Sub
```

I added the timer just in case it takes longer.  You can change the timeout, of course.

Comment: Hello @BGM, thank you for the reply. However, i was hoping for something a little less "hacky" that used more build in functions. Maybe the answer I'm looking for doesn't really exist. Regardless, i really liked the creative and the approach you took and upped the answer. But don't think I can give it a final answer yet. Thanks again.

Comment: @mateuscb Well, I'd like to say that I've been looking for ways to do this for a couple years.  The only way I've found is this "hacky" way.  I've written another script in autohotkey that does the same thing, but lets you select an account to log in with, and it also works in firefox.  The method above works for dotnet, and without anything but dotnet and api.  It works very well, actually.  The only shortcoming is if MS changes the order of the controls.  Also, I've only tried it on XP, and Sharepoint Services 2007; I'm working on it for Windows7.